Computing the spectrum of the operator $A(f)(t)=tf(t), A:L^1([0,1])\to L^1([0,1])$
Let $A$ be the bounded linear operator from the Banach space $L^1([0,1])$ to $L^1([0,1])$ defined as $A(f)(t) = tf(t)$. I've come to learn that then $A$'s spectrum should be $[0,1]$, but I'm a bit unsure how to prove this. That is, why for any $s\in[0,1]$ the operator $B_s\equiv sI - A$ cannot have a bounded inverse, when
$$B_s(f)(t) = sf(t) - tf(t) = f(t)(s-t)$$
We can certainly define
$$C_s(f)(t) := \frac{1}{s - t}f(t), t\neq s$$
and see that then for a.e. $t\in[0,1]$ we have
$$(B_s\circ C_s)(f)(t) = (C_s\circ B_s)(f)(t) = f(t)$$
but for e.g. $f\equiv 1$ on $[0,1]$ the norm
$$\|C_sf\| = \int_0^1\frac{1}{|t - s|}dt$$
is not defined. So, is that what suffices to conclude that the spectrum of $A$ must be the whole $[0,1]$?

The problem isn't that $C_s$ isn't bounded, it's that $C_s$ is not even well-defined because $B_s$ isn't even surjective to begin with.
Let $s \in[0;1]$. The constant map equal to $1$ is not an image : it it were, then for some $f\in L^1([0;1])$, for all $t\in [0;1]$, $(s-t)f(t)=1$. But $t\mapsto \frac{1}{s-t}$ is not in $L^1([0;1])$.

If $f \in L^1([0,1])$ is $0$ outside $(s-\epsilon, s+\epsilon)$, then $\|B_s f\| \le \epsilon \|f\|$, therefore $B_s$ is not invertible.
